# fetch tags inside php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get some div tags inside my php. The original code that is working looks like this:

```
echo "Date: ".$row{'date'}."<br>"."Day: ".$row{'day'}."<br>"."From Time: ".$row{'fromtime'}."<br>"."To Time: ".$row{'totime'}; //display the results
```

When I run this code, the data is gonna be below each other. I would like that each output from the database, is coming out in a row and in some div tags, so I can control it. I have tried to make it, but I am really in doubt how the syntax are?

```
<?php

echo "<div class="column1">""Date: ".$row{'date'}"</div>";
echo "<div class="column2">""Day: ".$row{'day'}"</div>";
echo "<div class="column3">""From Time: ".$row{'fromtime'}"</div>";
echo "<div class="column4">""To Time": ".$row{'totime'}"</div>";
?>
```

This dosent work. Does anybody know how I can solve this?

New code:

Thanks a lot for both your answers. I am actually thinking of putting in a table instead. When I print out the div, it looks like this:
http://postimg.org/image/jq60jujv1/

So I guess it would be something with

```
//fetch the data from the database 
Print"<h3>Return from database:</h3>"."<br>";

print '<table border="1">';
print '<tr>';
print '<td>date</td>';
print '<td>day</td>';
print '<td>fromtime</td>';
print '<td>totime</td>';
print '</tr>'."<br>";
print '</table>'."<br>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    print "<tr>"."<td>"."Date: ".$row{'date'}."</td>"."</tr>";
    print "<tr>"."<td>"."Day: ".$row{'day'}."</td>"."</tr>";
    print "<td>"."From Time: ".$row{'fromtime'}."</td>";
    print "<td>"."To Time: ".$row{'totime'}."</td>"."<br>";

}
```

or?
Best Regards
Mads

Comment: you have started echo with doubled quote `"` and you are applying class name with double quote again, so it will close string there, you can use single quote for class name.

Comment: `$row{'day'}` is a really unusual syntax for PHP. Shouldn't it be `$row['day']` or is this some fancy new way to access object properties?

Comment: It's just an alternative syntax.

Comment: I see, found it...still, I wouldn't recommend using curly brackets for array access, because the vast majority of code you encounter will use square brackets (for example, I never encountered it in the php docu other then in the short notice at the array syntax page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the wrapping quotation marks you use for `echo ".."` you can not use the same quotation marks inside that string:

```
echo "<div class="column1">""Date: ".$row{'date'}"</div>";
                 ^--- string ended
```

You can solve this in several ways, using single quotation marks inside is already suggested, but you can also escape the ones you are currently using:

```
echo "<div class=\"column1\">Date: ".$row{'date'}."</div>";
                 ^        ^
```

You can avoid all these problems by not using echo for output of all markup, but rather start/end php tags the place you actually want to print
variables or do some logic:

```
<div class="column1">Date: <?php echo $row{'date'}; ?></div>
```

### Output as table

A HTML table use the `<table>` and `</table>` tags,
`<tr>` is a table row, `<th>` for table
headers and `<td>` for regular table cells.

```
<?php
/* the code block where you connect to db etc.. */
?>
<table>
  <!-- headers -->
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>From</th>
    <th>To</th>
  </tr>
  <!-- Now a row for each new set of data, here you probably need to
    loop through some data set you retrieve from the database -->
  <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row{'date'};?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row{'day'};?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row{'fromtime'};?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row{'totime'};?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Should the <table>, <tr>, <td> look like: "<table>", "<tr>", "<td>"?

Comment: I updated loop in my example to use the same as you have in your question

Comment: You dont have to print everything you want for output. If you have any code above the HTML table then just end the PHP block with `?>`. I think it is a lot more difficult to read the code if everything is strings for output.

Comment: Can you see why my column 1 have another colour? http://postimg.org/image/sy4q746cp/

Comment: Yes, you do not close the PHP code block as my example accounts for. I'll update my example. Also note the `alternative syntax` I use on the `while`.

Comment: If you want the code you linked to to work, you need to do `while() { ?> <block of divs> <?php } ?>`. You can't mix PHP code blocks and HTML tags.

Comment: I didn't see that you have been writing a comment. I was updating every 2 minute :-/ I am looking at it now

Comment: perfect it solved the problem :-) Thanks a lot. I just have to play around with my css now. The result can be seen here: http://postimg.org/image/vkmhvkugj/

Where should I post the correct code, so someone else who have the same problem can see the solution?

Comment: Well, I guess my answer is the solution then? Accepting my answer will make it easier for others to find the answer that solved your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this instead of yours,

```
<?php
echo "<div class='column1'>"."Date: ".$row{'date'}."</div>";
echo "<div class='column2'>"."Day: ".$row{'day'}."</div>";
echo "<div class='column3'>"."From Time: ".$row{'fromtime'}."</div>";
echo "<div class='column4'>"."To Time: ".$row{'totime'}."</div>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have just edited my question. If you have time, I would be glad if you could take a look on it? Best Regards Mads

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
echo "<div class='column1'>Date: ".$row{'date'}."</div>
      <div class='column2'>Day: ".$row{'day'}."</div>
      <div class='column3'>From Time: ".$row{'fromtime'}."</div>
      <div class='column4'>To Time: ".$row{'totime'}."</div>";
?>
```

Edit:
If you want output as table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Day</th>
        <th>From Time</th>
        <th>To Time</th>
    </tr>   
<?php
    foreach($result as $row){
      echo "<tr><td>".$row{'date'}."</td>
          <td>".$row{'day'}."</td>
          <td>".$row{'fromtime'}."</td>
          <td>".$row{'totime'}."</td></tr>";
    }
?>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have just edited my question. If you have time, I would be glad if you could take a look on it? Best Regards Mads